# 'XFoil' object has no attribute '_lib'

Tags: python-3.x, package, attributeerror

Hello I'm trying to use Xfoil package using python. As the instructions say I installed the package and have written the following lines which are also shown in the documentation as a simple example. But, I always get error when running it in the second line xf=XFoil() and the error is
AttributeError: 'XFoil' object has no attribute '_lib'
Thanks for any suggestions

```
from xfoil import XFoil
xf = XFoil()

from xfoil.test import naca0012
xf.airfoil = naca0012

xf.Re = 1e6
xf.max_iter = 40
a, cl, cd, cm = xf.aseq(-20, 20, 0.5)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a, cl)
plt.show()
```

Comment: xfoil installation is not functioning properly if you get `AttributeError`

Comment: So, is there any suggestion that I should consider? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I installed xfoil in my windows OS with python 3.7.13. The import `from xfoil import XFoil` worked fine however as you mentioned `xf = XFoil()` resulted in an attribute error. I tried the installation guidelines given in the [Github page](https://github.com/DARcorporation/xfoil-python) and that worked fine. For brevity I have copy pasted the guidelines below:
create a file named `distutils.cfg` in `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils` with the following contents:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

I hope that helps.